# Prevent RabbitMQ from paging everything

Tags: rabbitmq

my RabbitMQ cluster (single-node) keeps paging-out **all** messages it gets to disk. In my case, I have an NVMe, but I would rather prefer to have messages in memory and only paged-out when the process hits the memory limit (which can be configured via config).

Digging into the docs, it seems like they made the decision (why?!) to **always** page **all** messages out onto disk. See [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html#paging):

> [...] All of them actively move data to disk and do not generally accumulate a significant backlog of messages in memory. [...]

Any ideas weather they introduced a config keyword to go back to "normal" behaviour? Normal meaning: store as much in memory as possible and use paging when memory reaches limit.